# Is Mercy's out-of-combat regen different from shield?

Tags: overwatch

Mercy regenerates health, but only when she has been out-of-combat for a couple of seconds. The only other concept of regenerating health in the game is shield, which also seems to regenerate out-of-combat. Is Mercy's regen any different from shield? Or does Mercy practically just have 200 points of shield health?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mercy's out of combat (more accurately, 'not being shot for 3 seconds') HP regen is significantly slower than shields. The regen does effectively mimic that property of shields, but at a slower rate (appears to be about 10hp/s for Mercy, vs 25/s for shields).

Comment: This piques my curiosity. If Mercy was given a Symmetra shield, would both her health and shield start regenerating simultaneously after 3 seconds?

Comment: Another point made by @NerdyCanuck in his(?) answer is that Mercy could be taken down to 1 HP, and she will fully regenerate to her maximum. A player with shields whose shields are destroyed and is subsequently taken down to 1 HP will only regenerate their shields and remain with only 1 HP.

Answer (score 1):

Notably, shields only regenerate themselves, and not the health under them - so if Zarya, with 200 health and 200 shields, takes 300 damage, her shields will only bring her back to 300 combined health (100 health and 200 shields).  Mercy, on the other hand, seems to regain her entire health pool.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I would suggest that it's one way in which her health differs from shields, especially give  the clear audio cue you get when your shields drop - a Mercy player counting on this mechanic would have to watch her health very closely.

Comment: But saying shields only regenerate themselves when comparing -shields themselves- to Mercy's health doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Fair, but what I'm trying to get at is that Mercy's health regenerates fully, which may not be semantically different from just saying she has all shields, but it is meaningfully different.  There are tactical considerations specific to shielded characters that are shared by all shielded characters, and Mercy does not share these.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question. Anyway, comments are not for extended discussion.